# SharePoint 2010 - Client Object Model -- Approve File

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Does anybody know what is replacement for SPFile.Approve() method in Client Object Model ?
Class Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File does not have this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
item.set_item('_ModerationStatus', 0);
item.update();
context.load(item);
context.executeQueryAsync(successFunction, failureFunction);
```

It works for me in a simple scenario.

Comment: can you provide any link for more details.

Answer (score 6):

```
//upload file to document library
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File newFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fci);
//if target doclib has versioning enabled you will not be able to modify the Approval Status until file is checked in.
newFile.CheckIn("Programmatically Checked In", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery(); 

//get the File's underlying ListItem object
ListItem item = uploadFile.ListItemAllFields;
//use SPModerationStatusType
item["_ModerationStatus"] = SPModerationStatusType.Approved;
item.Update();
context.Load(item);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```